# How to solve "Observable.share is not a function" Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I use cache structure in ionic 2. I define an observable array. I record the data that is returned from the server here. But every time this shape gives me a mistake. How do I solve it?

```js
 marketArray : Observable<any>; /* GLOBAL */   this.http.get(this.base_url,header).map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
      loader.dismissAll();
      this.marketArray = this.cache.loadFromObservable(this.base_url, data["Table"]);
      
    }, (error)=>{
      loader.dismissAll();
      this.marketler();
    });
```

Comment: Please put your solution in an answer instead of editing it into your question.

Comment: The error given by this snippet is not the error described in title.

Comment: @Can Kurucu I just posted your solution as [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) (which keeps me from getting any credit for it). If you want to receive any upvotes for the answer, please post your answer separately and I'll delete the one I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally posted by [Can Kurucu](/users/8090868/can-kurucu):

I solved this by

```js
let req = this.http.get(this.base_url, header).map(res=>res.json());
this.marketArray = this.cache.loadFromObservable(this.base_url, req);
```

Answer (score 7):

Add `import "rxjs/add/operator/share";` to the beginning of the source file.

(edit: import path fixed as pointed out in comments - thanks!)

Comment: Yes, I added. But the problem continues "observable.share is not a function"

Comment: Ok ! It was "import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';" (the "add" part was in the wrong place). :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this in newer versions of RxJs, the import statement should be:

```
import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';
```